# Jasmine Grunt, Backbone, Require, Routes etc

Tags: backbone.js, routes, requirejs, gruntjs, jasmine

i have a question. I have a full app, a lot of view(backbone), models, everything using require, routes etc. When my app is on production i have a single file main.js, like this:

```
<script data-main="main-gdfgfda.js" src="url/require.js"></script>
```

But i cant run tasks on my spec.

MY views work like this:

```
define(function(require){
    "use strict";

    var $ = require('jquery'),
        Backbone = require('backbone'),
        ContentFactory = require('views/ContentFactory'),
        imagesLoaded = require('imagesloaded'),
        ShareView = require('views/ui/ShareView');

    var myView = Backbone.View.extend(....
});
```

And isnted i have some variables in php files.

And i cant running tests in this framework, there is a lot of error because depedency and et, what should i do, what is the best way to acess myView to start testing using jasmine?

If i put in jasmine template it will work? I cant just run SRC folder/*js, because there is a lot of dependecys and etc.

What should i do? Thx